# How to Display Audio Information?

Tags: matlab, audio, audio-recording

How can I display coefficients of audio signal when plotting an audio file in Matlab?

I am fairly new to Matlab so this could be a stupid question. I have searched for similar things but haven't come across anything similar.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "coefficients of audio signal"? And how do you plot "an audio file"? You must have imported it somehow into a Matlab signal: how do you do it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to read the sound. Considering that you have it stored in wav format, you can use for example `[X, fs] = wavread('sound_name.wav');`. `fs` would be your sample rate and `X` would be matrix of samples [number of samples]x[number of channels]. By default it will read sound in doubles, but it can be changed. See `help wavread` for details.
Then you can display raw waveform by simply ploting it: `plot(X);`. Or if you need spectrum of the sound, you can window signal and then apply FFT. In this case [voicebox](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/voicebox/voicebox.html) toolbox would be useful: `F = enframe(X, hamming(win_len), fix(win_len/2)); sp = rfft(F.'); imagesc(10*log(abs(sp)));`
There are also lots of handy functions in Matlab signal processing toolbox.